# Acumatica field not showing on View Current

Tags: c#, acumatica

In the Contact Screen (CR302000) I have created a Tab with a grid that Displays all the orders related to the selected Contact through a SOOrder. UsrInstitutionalContact. The view works correctly on the grid.

I need to link the Order Number from the grid to the SO.

I did all the steps to make it work and works fine except for one problem. I cannot get the current `OrdNbr`.

I tested the process **hardcoding the OrdNbr** to make sure that the:
`PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);` works.

This is the grid displaying the fields as I wanted working correctly.

[image: The Grid]

This is the view that I'm using for the grid

```
public SelectFrom<Contact>.
         LeftJoin<SOOrder>.On<SOOrderExt.usrInstitutionalContact.IsEqual<Contact.contactID>>.
         Where<Contact.contactID.IsEqual<Contact.contactID.FromCurrent>>.View ContactOrders;
```

Here is the Action code and what I have tried so far without any success:

```
 1 public PXAction<Contact> ViewSalesOrder;
 2
 3 [PXButton]
 4 protected virtual void viewSalesOrder()
 5 {
 6   SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
 7        
 8   if (ContactOrders.Current != null)
 9   {
10        Contact curRow = Base.ContactCurrent.Current;
11        SOOrder soorder = SelectFrom<SOOrder>.
12              Where<SOOrder.orderNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.View.Select(Base, "EMC000994");
13                       
14          graph.Document.Current = soorder;
15            PXRedirectHelper.TryRedirect(graph, PXRedirectHelper.WindowMode.NewWindow);
16   }
17 }
```

**Line 10** is not returning the OrdNbr. In fact, it does not show any field from the SO, but it shows it on the grid.  I need to retrieve the **current ordrNbr** to pass it to the SOOrder FBQL.

**Line 12**, as you can see I hardcoded the OrdNbr just for the purpose of testing the process.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that on the PXGrid, you have the property SyncPosition set to True. This would ensure when you click on a grid row, it "selects" it and makes it available using Current/FromCurrent.